# Cross-Domain POST in JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, web-applications, cross-domain, jboss7.x

I have a web application in a cloud server. One of my controllers of my web application externalizes URLs to be accessed through a mobile app (using JavaScript; I´m using Titanium to develop for Android and iOS). I can access the GET methods without any problem and I obtain what I desire, but when I call the POST methods to send information to be processed, I get Bad Server - HTTP Error. To protect my URLs I use BASIC authentication configured in my application and in JBoss (standalone.xml file). When I access the POST methods from a form (using JQuery Ajax) inside the web application, that´s OK, so I think this is a Cross-Domain problem.

Is there any configuration to be done in JBoss so my web application can receive POST calls from any other domains (of course, providing the correct username/password pair).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are saying that the web call works fine if you use GET, but if you switch it to POST it fails?  Create a basic web service method with perhaps no parameters and make the POST call.  I'd be more likely to guess your problem is with the parameters you are passing.  Are you passing them in the query string or in the body of the message?

Comment: I second @Martin. If it works for `GET`s, although not guaranteed, it *should* work for `POST` as well. Didn't you have to make some configuration to enable `GET`s? Are you 500% sure you are sending everything the `POST` needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally these cross-domain issues have to do with the browser, not the server. The browser will limit your ability to use AJAX updates to the domain of the page you are on. There are some workarounds such as JSONP, but I don't know if that can work for POST.

We decided to use a 3rd party proxy library [HTTP Proxy Servlet](https://github.com/dsmiley/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet). This proxy servlet allows you to POST as though to your locally accessible domain with a simple web.xml addition. Doing this, we never have to mess with JSONP either, just straight JSON works fine.

We are using it to forward several different paths to several different servers (you can have more than 1 forwarder using this method in the same web app). Our web.xml is just a series of servlet mappings (one for each external RESTful service pointing to the base paths):

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyOneProxy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
         <param-value>http://external-web-app.com/basePath</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>log</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyOneProxy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/internalBasePath/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```